# Running wp-cli commands through SSH with phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib, wp-cli

I am automating installing multiple WordPress blogs on a server. Basically, I need to run multiple wp-cli commands.

Using phpseclib and doing `exec()`, doesn't work...

When I do something like:

```
$ssh->exec('wp core download');
```

I will just get:

> /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory

Even though I can run it fine, in a normal ssh session...

If I try and `$ssh->write` the command out and do '\n' it doesn't seem to do anything. Even if I just try to do a simple command like: `touch foo.txt`

Although that test "touch" command will work with exec...

The system is Ubuntu 14.04...

Any ideas?

I have to connect via SSH from PHP to do this for multiple domains on a server, as new customers come on.

Comment: On a side note, I have tried exec using the full path to wp-cli which is setup as wp in /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to PHP probably needs to be defined. When you SH in with the regular SSH client it's probably running any number of [Bash initialization files](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html).

In light of this I have two thoughts.

1. Try to use a PTY. eg.

   ```
   $ssh->enablePTY(); 
   $ssh->exec('passwd'); 
   echo $ssh->read();
   ```

   More info: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/pty.html
2. Are you doing `$ssh->read('[prompt]');` after doing the `write("command\n")`? You may need to read the stream to get the command to actually be run.